# applet group layout net-beans

Tags: netbeans, applet, netbeans-6.9

I am working on a online examination system using APPLETS. I am using the net beans ide(6.9). The project requies me to use group layout for panels. How do i do that in net beans6.9.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the layout tools in Netbeans, they're all driven off the class type. Right click on your project and go to `New -> Other -> Swing GUI Forms -> JApplet Form`. Once you create one of that type, you'll get the editor which allows you to design your applet layout whenever you open that class.